# xampp localhost doesn't open the file the way it is

Tags: html, css, xampp

So i have a html file, and if i open it using localhost server while xampp runs the site opens but with a style that I used before that and now it's deleted, but if I only click on the file without being connected to localhost it opens it correctly, my xampp also makes some errors while I tried to close it.
How can I open the file in the correct form from the server.

Comment: The issues with XAMPP's errors might be a separate issue, and probably worth a separate post. Either way, you should put the exact error, instead of "makes some errors".

Comment: I restarted my computer like 5 times an it started working,but I still don't get the issue, thank you anyway